# Python: Converting two sequential 2-byte registers (4 bytes) into IEEE floating-point big endian

Tags: python, hex, byte

I am hooking up an instrument to a laptop over TCP/IP. I have been using a python package to talk to it, and have it return numbers. There are two probes hooked up to this instrument, and I believe these are the bytes corresponding to the temperature readings of these two probes.

The instrument, by default, is set to Big Endian and these data should be of a 32-bit floating point variety - meaning that the variable (b) in the code chunk represents two numbers. b is representative of the output that I would get from the TCP functions.

```
>>> b = [16746, 42536, 16777, 65230]
>>>
```

My goal in this is to convert these into their float values, and automating the process. Currently, I am running b through the (hex) function to retrieve the hexadecimal equivalents of each byte:

```
>>> c =[hex(value) for value in b]
>>>
>>> c
>['0x416a', '0xa628', '0x4189', '0xfece']
>>>
```

... then I have manually created `data_1` and `data_2` below to match these hex values, then unpacked them using `struct.unpack` as I found in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093485/how-to-interpret-4-bytes-as-a-32-bit-float-using-python):

```
>>> data_1 = b'\x41\x6a\xa6\x28'
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>f', data_1)
>(14.665565490722656,)
>>> data_2 = b'\x41\x89\xfe\xce'
>>> struct.unpack('>f', data_2)
>(17.24941635131836,)
>>>
```

Some questions:

- Am I fundamentally missing something? I am a biologist by trade, and usually a `R` programmer, so Python is relatively new to me.
- I am primarily looking for a streamlined way to get from the TCP output (`b`) to the number outputs of struct.unpack. The eventual goal of this project is to constantly be polling the sensors for data, which will be graphed/displayed on screen as well as being saved to a .csv.

Thank you!

Comment: If you write `hex(..)` the format is *little endian*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below produces same numbers you found:

```
import struct

def bigIntToFloat(bigIntlist):
    pair = []
    for bigInt in bigIntlist:
        pair.append(bytes.fromhex(format(bigInt, '04x')))
        if len(pair) == 2:
            yield struct.unpack('>f', b''.join(pair))[0]
            pair = []
```

The key parts are `format(bigInt, '04x')` which turns an integer into a hex value without the (in this case) unneeded '0x', while ensuring it's zero-padding to four characters, and `bytes.fromhex`, which turns the output of that into a bytes object suitable for `struct.unpack`.

As for whether you're missing something, that's hard for me to say, but I will say that the numbers you give look "reasonable" - that is, if you had the ordering wrong, I'd expect the numbers to be vastly different from each other, rather than slightly.

Comment: Thank you Nathan! This worked perfectly, except sometimes it would fail when `format(bigInt, 'x')` returned a hex value shorter than 4 digits. In this case it was necessary to add preceding zeroes before running it into `bytes.fromhex()`:       

`a = format(bigInt, 'x'); while len(a)<4: a = "0"+a`

Sorry, don't know how to do code chunks in comments properly

Comment: @Umi Excellent! I didn't think of the zero-padding problem; fyi, you can fix that more cleanly with `a = format(bigInt, '04x')`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `struct.pack` to turn those numbers back into a byte string, then `unpack` as you were doing. `pack` and `unpack` can also work with multiple values at a time; the only snag is that `pack` expects individual arguments instead of a list, so you must put a `*` in front to expand the list.

```
>>> struct.unpack('>2f', struct.pack('>4H', *b))
(14.665565490722656, 17.24941635131836)
```